# Selecting closest subset of variables in r based on the highest and Lowest Values from another Variable

Tags: r, unix, dplyr, logic

I have this file:

```
id  egs aol pH  marm    fat PCQ
1   12  59  5.52    420 3   216
2   9   70  5.38    330 2   225
3   8   50  5.54    360 2   225
4   10  58  5.48    340 3   227
5   12  57  5.41    400 2   227
6   10  62  5.32    350 3   231
7   18  66  5.49    350 2   234
8   13  57  5.49    320 3   241
9   11  61  5.65    400 3   242
10  9   69  5.43    320 2   246
11  11  60  5.52    390 2   248
12  19  66  5.48    330 2   281
13  11  73  5.53    380 2   283
14  20  72  5.46    370 3   284
15  9   71  5.36    500 3   284
16  11  63  5.50    380 3   285
17  15  68  5.33    NA  NA  286
18  17  58  5.43    340 3   288
19  17  61  5.44    350 2   291
20  11  73  6.15    340 3   292
21  19  67  5.67    390 2   296
22  13  76  5.53    360 3   297
23  15  64  5.75    320 3   300
24  11  69  5.75    NA  NA  300
25  15  68  5.47    390 3   317
```

And I need select the three highest values and three lowest values for PCQ, and the closest values within `egs, aol,pH,marm,fat`. So, I would select this:

```
id  egs aol pH  marm    fat PCQ
1   12  59  5.52    420 3   216
5   12  57  5.41    400 2   227
7   18  66  5.49    350 2   234
21  19  67  5.67    390 2   296
22  13  76  5.53    360 3   297
25  15  68  5.47    390 3   317
```

OBS: this is just a example, I don´t need select exactly these values, as long as the logic remains.

I tried commands based on dplyr like this:

```
library(dplyr)
date %>%
  arrange((PCQ)) %>% slice(1:3) %>%
  filter(PCQ - lag(PCQ, default = 0))
```

but unsuccessful to move forward. Some suggestion?

OBS: Can be unix language too. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `more similarity among the values from egs aol pH  marm  fat` ? What is the logic to select values?

Comment: the closest values within each variable, for example, the closest values within pH, but that for all variables.